# Uploading a file using extjs

Tags: java, file-upload, struts, extjs4.1

i am trying to upload a file to server through extjs. I am using struts and java. The path from which i need to upload the file will be constant. so there will be no need for a file chooser.
the code i have written is like this

```
var file="c://folder/file.txt";

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: fileupload.action,
    params:{
    fileName:file
    }
});
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong with this?

Comment: What exactly is the issue that you are having?

Comment: hi, thanks for responding. Since i am just passing the file name to the action class, i cannot find a way to receive it as a file on the server side. Is the code i have written above correct?

Comment: Take a look at the examples: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/form/file-upload.html